# Conditional options in Plot

Tags: plotting

I was hoping to incorporate an `If` function into a `Plot` option, as in

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> If[Sin[t] > 0, LightGreen, LightRed]]
```

or

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> If[Sin[t] > 0, Dashed, Thick]]
```

to no avail. Is it possible to pass an `If` to the plot options?

I know that I can manually accomplish the effect via `Piecewise`, but I have more complicated applications in mind where I would not want to manually precompute the interval(s) on which my piecewise defined function would need to be defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is yet another crack at this problem.

```
ConditionalPlot[func_, condition_, varrange_, trueopts_, falseopts_] :=
  Module[{plottrue, plotfalse},
  plottrue = Plot[If[condition, func], varrange, trueopts];
  plotfalse = Plot[If[Not[condition], func], varrange, falseopts];
  Show[plottrue, plotfalse, PlotRange -> All]]
```

The first argument is the function or list of functions you want to plot.  The second argument is the condition you want to apply.  The third argument is the variable and range to plot in the form `{x,xmin,xmax}`.  The third and fourth arguments are the options you apply when the condition is true or false, respectively.

For example, the plot you mentioned in your question can be had by

```
ConditionalPlot[Sin[x], 
 Sin[x] > 0, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> LightGreen, PlotStyle -> Dashed}, {Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> LightRed, PlotStyle -> Thick}]
```

[image]

This is versitile, you can give it a compound condition like

```
ConditionalPlot[Sin[x], 
 Sin[x] > .7 || Sin[x] < -.7, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> LightGreen, PlotStyle -> Dashed}, {Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> LightRed, PlotStyle -> Thick}]
```

[image]

You can give it multiple functions to plot

```
ConditionalPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, 
 Sin[x] > Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi},
  {PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> 14}, 
      {PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick,Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Note that any global options you want to apply to the image in general should go in the `trueopts` as it is given to `Show` first.

Comment: This is quite handy and does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Applying the method I used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25169/how-to-plot-filling-under-a-curve/25216#25216) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25704/how-can-i-shade-specific-regions-between-two-curves-in-a-plot/25709#25709), we can use `ParametricPlot` with `MeshShading`:

```
 ParametricPlot[{t, u Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {LightRed, LightGreen},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since one may specify arbitrary `MeshFunctions`, it does provide some flexibility.

```
ParametricPlot[{t, u Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 - Cos[2 #1] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {LightRed, LightGreen},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

One of the comments mentions a desire to control the `PlotStyle`.  `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading` may be used with `Plot` to control the style of the plotted line.

```
With[{meshfns = {#2 - Cos[2 #1] &}, mesh = {{0}}},
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{t, u Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1},
   BoundaryStyle -> None,
   MeshFunctions -> meshfns, Mesh -> mesh, 
   MeshShading -> {LightRed, LightGreen}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False],
  Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   MeshFunctions -> meshfns, Mesh -> mesh, MeshStyle -> None,
   MeshShading -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Green, Thick]}]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

Not sure there is a direct way to do it but you can split the function up in two:

```
Plot[{
  If[Sin[t] > 0, Sin[t]],
  If[Sin[t] <= 0, Sin[t]]
  }, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Filling -> Axis,
 PlotStyle -> {
     (* Use same color for both so it looks like the same function *)
     Directive[ColorData[1][1], Dashed],
     Directive[ColorData[1][2], Thick]
    },
 FillingStyle -> {1 -> LightGreen, 2 -> LightRed}]
```

[image: plot]

Not that giving [`FillingStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FillingStyle.html) two colors it uses one for "below" and the other for "above":

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {LightRed, LightGreen}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The latter is example is quite useful! But at other times I need to adjust the style of the graph based on the function itself. Is it possible to call a plot option which is a function of the input function itself? If so, how?

Comment: @JohnD Don't know if it's even possible for style, but for color-only you can look at `ColorFunction`

Comment: @JohnD, can you give an example of the type of more complex situation you are looking at?  The second example ssch gave is pretty general and should work for any function that goes above and below the `Filling` parameter.

Comment: @JasonB: The second item in the original post is one such example. I agree that works for `Filling` but I also need to use other options (e.g., `PlotStyle`).

Answer (score 3):

I would make two different plots and combine them with a `Show` command, like

```
Show[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotStyle->Dashed,FillingStyle -> LightGreen, PlotRange -> {0, All}], 
 Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightRed,
   PlotStyle->Thick,PlotRange -> {All, 0}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The downside to this is if the function and/or condition (in general) is complicated, I have to manually precompute the pieces, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @JohnD, the two examples you gave are simple enough that this method works great.  What is an example where this method would get too tedious?  It's possible that even for the more complicated tasks you have envisioned, we could make a list of `Plot`s which we create using `Table`, and then feed that list to `Show`.

Answer (score 3):

One more way!

```
colors = {Red, Green};
Plot[Evaluate@{If[Sin[t] > 0, Sin[t]], If[Sin[t] <= 0, Sin[t]]}, {t,0, 2 Pi},
Filling -> Axis,PlotStyle -> Transpose@{{Dashed, Thick}, colors}, 
FillingStyle -> MapIndexed[#2 -> Directive[Opacity[0.25], #] &, colors]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to generate the plot for each domain/range that are specified. Then thread them together with [Show function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html).

A simple example:

```
Show[
     RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red],
     RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 > 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
]
```

[image: region]