# Plot when multiple conditions are satified

Tags: plotting, conditional

I have a code which goes like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tbl = Table[{x, N[x^2]}, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}];
const1 = 2;
const2 = 1.2;
newrow[{k_, r1_}] := {k, r1, (k + r1) 50/const2, (k + r1) 1.6/2.6};
newtbl = Map[newrow, tbl];

Export["file" <> ToString[const1] <> ".dat", newtbl];

rowlength = Length[newtbl];
xaxis = Table[newtbl[[i, 1]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
yaxis1 = Table[newtbl[[i, 2]], {i, 1, rowlength}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis, #}] & /@ {yaxis1}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k\[Rho]", "\[Omega]"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The output graph looks like this:

[image]

In the exported file one can see that there are 4 columns and I am plotting 1st and 2nd column. 
Now, I would like to plot with certain condition that has to be imposed. E.g. I want to plot 2nd colum only when

1. the third column value is between 1000 and 2000, and also
2. the fourth column value is greater than 10 (it can go upto any value)

I want both this condition to be satisfied simultaneously and generate plot. In this case one can see that condition gets satisfied only when the first column has value in between 4.5 to 6.4.How can this be accomplished?

The solution that is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/conditional-options-in-plot) does not serve the purpose.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen Select and Cases?

Comment: never heard about it. Could you hel with that?

Comment: Have you searched the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I cannot understand how to give 2 condition simultaneously

Comment: There are examples which use multiple conditions. Did you go through the examples in the documentation? You can use `And`, which has the shorthand `&&`.

Comment: Recommended reading: at least first 6 sections of http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FindingExpressionsThatMatchAPattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's create your table in a simpler way.

```
row[{k_, r1_}] := {k, r1, (k + r1) 50/1.2, (k + r1) 1.6/2.6}
tbl = Table[row@{x, x^2}, {x, 0.1, 10., 0.1}];
```

Now let's filter the table on the 3rd item of each tuple.

```
Cases[tbl, {x_, y_, p_ /; LessEqual[1000., p, 2000], q_} -> {x, y, p, q}]
```

> ```
> {{4.5, 20.25, 1031.25, 15.2308}, {4.6, 21.16, 1073.33, 15.8523}, 
>  {4.7, 22.09, 1116.25, 16.4862}, {4.8, 23.04, 1160., 17.1323}, 
>  {4.9, 24.01, 1204.58, 17.7908}, {5., 25., 1250., 18.4615}, 
>  {5.1, 26.01, 1296.25, 19.1446}, {5.2, 27.04, 1343.33, 19.84}, 
>  {5.3, 28.09, 1391.25, 20.5477}, {5.4, 29.16, 1440., 21.2677}, 
>  {5.5, 30.25, 1489.58, 22.}, {5.6, 31.36, 1540., 22.7446}, 
>  {5.7, 32.49, 1591.25, 23.5015}, {5.8, 33.64, 1643.33, 24.2708}, 
>  {5.9, 34.81, 1696.25, 25.0523}, {6., 36., 1750., 25.8462}, 
>  {6.1, 37.21, 1804.58, 26.6523}, {6.2, 38.44, 1860., 27.4708}, 
>  {6.3, 39.69, 1916.25, 28.3015}, {6.4, 40.96, 1973.33, 29.1446}}
> ```
>
> Note that in every case the 4th item is greater than 10., so there is no need to filter on the 4th item (if there were, we write `q_ /; q > 10`). Consequently, we make the plot with:

```
data = Cases[tbl, {x_, y_, p_ /; LessEqual[1000., p, 2000], _} -> {x, y}];
ListLinePlot[data,
  Mesh -> Full,
  AxesLabel -> {"kρ", "ω"},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]